# Could not move my Obstacle Avoidance Robot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, robotics

I am newbie to Raspberry Pi 3. I want to make a Obstacle Avoidance Robot using Raspberry Pi 3. I connected my Raspberry Pi through putty for remote access. I successfully connected remotely and wrote the code.

The code is shown below:

board:- Raspberrypi3 modelB

Motor Driver:-L293D

```python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO                    #Import GPIO library
import time

#Import time library
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                    # programming the GPIO by BCM pin numbers

TRIG = 17
ECHO = 27
led = 22

m11=16
m12=12
m21=21
m22=20

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)                  # initialize GPIO Pin as outputs
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)                   # initialize GPIO Pin as input
GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)                  

GPIO.setup(m11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(m12,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(m21,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(m22,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(led, 1)

time.sleep(5)

def stop():
    print "stop"
    GPIO.output(m11, 0)
    GPIO.output(m12, 0)
    GPIO.output(m21, 0)
    GPIO.output(m22, 0)

def forward():
    GPIO.output(m11, 1)
    GPIO.output(m12, 0)
    GPIO.output(m21, 1)
    GPIO.output(m22, 0)
    print "Forward"

def back():
    GPIO.output(m11, 0)
    GPIO.output(m12, 1)
    GPIO.output(m21, 0)
    GPIO.output(m22, 1)
    print "back"

def left():
    GPIO.output(m11, 0)
    GPIO.output(m12, 0)
    GPIO.output(m21, 1)
    GPIO.output(m22, 0)
    print "left"

def right():
    GPIO.output(m11, 1)
    GPIO.output(m12, 0)
    GPIO.output(m21, 0)
    GPIO.output(m22, 0)
    print "right"

stop()
count=0
while True:
 i=0
 avgDistance=0
 for i in range(5):
  GPIO.output(TRIG, False)                 #Set TRIG as LOW
  time.sleep(0.1)                                   #Delay

  GPIO.output(TRIG, True)                  #Set TRIG as HIGH
  time.sleep(0.00001)                           #Delay of 0.00001 seconds
  GPIO.output(TRIG, False)                 #Set TRIG as LOW
   #78th line..my code was struck up in this while loop
  while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:#Check whether the ECHO is LOW                
       GPIO.output(led, False)             
  pulse_start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:              #Check whether the ECHO is HIGH
       GPIO.output(led, False) 
  pulse_end = time.time()
  pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start #time to get back the pulse to sensor

  distance = pulse_duration * 17150        #Multiply pulse duration by 17150 (34300/2) to get distance

  distance = round(distance,2)                 #Round to two decimal points
  avgDistance=avgDistance+distance

 avgDistance=avgDistance/5
 print avgDistance
 flag=0
 if avgDistance < 15:      #Check whether the distance is within 15 cm range
    count=count+1
    stop()
    time.sleep(1)
    back()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    if (count%3 ==1) & (flag==0):
     right()
     flag=1
    else:
     left()
     flag=0
    time.sleep(1.5)
    stop()
    time.sleep(1)
 else:
    forward()
    flag=0
```

When I tried to move my robot forward, back,left and Right. It is not moving. And my code is stuck up in while loop.. which is in 78.(number mentioned in code). What is the problem there? Is there any wrong in code or can't I connect my Raspberru Pi through putty??? If yes, is there any other way I can connect remotely my Raspberry Pi, and work on Robot...sorry for my bad English. Please help.

Comment: What you need is HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Distance Sensor. You may want to tale a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669925/c-to-python-code-arduino-to-raspberry-pi-using-ultrasonic/72669974#72669974 Also you need picamera2.